# Problems updating BIOS via Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bios

I have a Compaq Presario V4000 laptop currently running version F.03 BIOS. After spending a while looking through HP and Compaq's websites, Archive.org and Google, I determined that the BIOS updater for the laptop was `sp32790.exe`on HP's FTP server at `ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp32501-33000/sp32790.exe` with the readme at `ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp32001-32500/sp32790.html`.

As the laptop is running Ubuntu(15.04), I cannot run the exe directly. I have tried running it in FreeDOS, which errored: `This program cannot be run in DOS mode`.

Trying in Wine errors:

`Cannot open driver Flash1.sys. The driver is not existed or the OS is not in administrator privilege.`

...after accepting the T's & C's, however leaves a BIOS folder in Wine's C drive:

```
- BIOS
|   - WF
|   |   - 3081F17.WPH
|   |   - flash1.ini
|   |   - FLASH1.sys
|   |   - mfc42.dll
|   |   - msvcp60.dll
|   |   - msvcrt.dll
|   |   - Phlash9X.vxd
|   |   - PHLASH.INI
|   |   - PHLASH.LOG
|   |   - PhlashLc.dll
|   |   - PhlashNT.sys
|   |   - wflash.exe
|   |   - WinPhlash.exe
```

Unpacking the original exe reveals `3081F17_WIN.exe` which then contains the same files as above, save the log.

Running WinPhlash.exe via Wine errors:

`Failed to initialise the driver. Driver failed to provide access to the BIOS memory. Error code: -122`

Any ideas on how I could install this update?

Note the laptop **WILL NOT** boot from USB(at least on the current BIOS. How ironic.)

Comment: What about boot CD?

Comment: A boot CD of what? I've tried FreeDOS already and I only have Windows 7 64bit disc which will not run(processor is 32bit)

Comment: It's a windows only program; you're out of luck if you don't have a copy of windows to run it with.  Check and see if they have a regular dos version that you can at least easily run either by booting the prepared freedos iso or your own and then running it.

Answer (score 1):

A late solution, as I opened your question before I have found the final solution. And I've just succeeded from my bios update, which has the similar situation as yours: only windows utility program for bios update is provided. So would like to add the exactly solution here:

1. extract bios file (3081F17.WPH) by e.g. [Uniextractor](https://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract).
2. create a bootable [FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org/) usb.
3. download phoenix bios flash tool [Phlash16](https://www.wimsbios.com/phoenixflasher.jsp).
4. change 3081F17.WPH name to BIOS.WPH, and put it and PHLASH16.exe in the same directory in the usb drive.
5. boot to FreeDOS, and go to the directory where you have put PHLASH16.exe and BIOS.WPH, and write the command:

> PHLASH16 /S /X /FORCE

then press ENTER

More information you can read [here](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/archive/index.php?thread-7426.html) as well as the whole website specific for bios topic.